# Modificar Script configuración php para mostrar errores

Tags: php, unix, macos

Pues bien, la pregunta es básicamente lo que pongo en el titulo. Actualmente, tengo el servidor en Mac OS, no sé si los ficheros de configuración son los mismos que en distribuciones Linux. Quiero modificar la configuración del servidor, para que se muestren los warnings durante la ejecución.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo poniendo `error_reporting` con los parámetros que necesitas al principio del script. Hay varios niveles de reporte de errores, [el Manual de PHP lo explica muy bien](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php), y en el idioma de Cervantes, con ejemplos de código muy concretos.

Comment: ¿Estas usando alguna app como MAMP?